Proving that semi-open in the whole space implies semi-open in the subspace
Problem:  Let $A\subset Y \subset X$, where $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ a subspace. If $A$ is semi-open in $X$ then it is also semi-open in $Y$.
I will use the following definition of semi-open.
Definition. Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A\subset X$. The $A$ is called semi-open if there exists an open set $G$ in $X$ such that $G\subset A \subset \bar{G}$.
My Attempt:
Since $A$ is semi-open in $X$, there exists an open set $G$ in $X$ such that
$$G\subset A \subset \bar{G}.$$
Now, $G\subset Y$ (since $G\subset A$ and $A\subset Y$) and so
$$G=G\cap Y\subset A\cap Y\subset \bar{G}\cap Y.$$
But $\bar{G}\cap Y = (\bar{G})_Y$. We obtain
$$G\subset (\bar{G})_Y. $$
Note that $G$ is open in $Y$ because $G=G\cap Y$, where $G$ is open in $X$. My goal is to come up
$$G\subset A \subset (\bar{G})_Y.$$
So, it seems that I have to show that $(\bar{G})_Y=\bar{G}$? If so, then I got confused on  how to show that $\bar{G}\subset (\bar{G})_Y$.
I know that $\bar{G}$ is the smallest closed superset of $G$ and what I've done so far is that the set $(\bar{G})_Y$ is a superset of $G$. How can I proceed then because $(\bar{G})_Y$ may not be closed in $X$.
Need someone to help on this.
Thanks.

If $C$ is closed in $X$ then $C \cap Y$ is closed in $Y$. This follows because $X \setminus C$ is open in $X$.

Ah okay. My proof is almost there if i only remember that result. So, the set $(\bar{G})_Y$ is a closed superset of $G$ and so, $G\subset \bar{G}\subset (\bar{G})_Y$. Thank you very much @cooper.hat
